# Does the negative ずに form have a connective function like the te form does?

Tags: particle-に, negation, auxiliary-ず

I know ずに is a form of negation for verbs, but I'm uncertain as to how its being used in the following context other than as a negation for the verb わかる.

> 昨晩アインは夜明けまで時間をくれた。それまでに生きるか死ぬかを決めさせてくれるという。結局選んだ道は、このままなにもわから**ずに**死んでいくことではなく、ツヴァイとして、殺し屋として生きていくことだった。いつか自分という存在を取り戻すためにも、今はツヴァイでいるしかないのだ。

Seeing as how the verb 死んで comes directly after the わからずに, it made me wonder why there's not a particle between the two verbs. Unless the に **is** the particle here, my brain thought the lack of a particle could be explained by the ずに form being able to connect two verbs like the te form can.

I've not formally studied the ずに form, so I have no means of confirming nor disproving my brain's analytical explanation. Although I highly doubt the ずに form can be used as a connective form, a second opinion would be much appreciated as to what the ずに in the above context is doing.

TDLR: (1) Is the ずに in the above a negation of the verb its attached to,

(2) or is it a negation with only the ず form which makes the に a particle,

(3) or a mashed up combination of the above which would make the に a part of the negation and a particle,

(4) or is the ずに a negating connective... 'thing' for the わかる verb and 死んで　verb,

(５) or something else entirely?

> Asking as I've seen multiple [questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27361/26406) and [answers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9591/26406) using both ず and ずに as interchangeable words for the same form of negation, so I have no clue as to what is going or is applicable in my own sentence.

Comment: Just copying from it's weblio definition: 連用修飾語として用いられる。…ないで。

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9566/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72147/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27361/9831

Comment: @Chocolate It's because of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27361/26406 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9566/26406 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72147/26406 I'm confused as to whether the ずに in the above context is a ず form + に particle, or just ずに verb negation/'adverb maker' according to https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9591/26406.

Answer (score 4):

ずに is a conjunctive negative form for verbs which comes from the classical Japanese auxiliary verb ず (which is still used in limited occasions in modern Japanese).

This ず was/is added to the end of the 未然形 of a verb and is the 基本形 (and 終止形 and 連用形) of the old negative 'tense'. There are [plenty](http://www.irohabook.com/japanese-classics-zu) [of](https://kb-study.com/aux-zu/) [websites](https://tyottojuku.com/study/%E5%8F%A4%E6%96%87/2540) dealing with this, so have a look if you're interested.

Anyway, getting back to ～ずに.

～ずに is what we get when we add 「に」 to 「ず」; pretty straightforward, right?

So what is this に, then? According to [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166082), に can be used (as a sort of adjunct) to 動作・作用の行われ方、その状態のあり方を表す (show the way something is or how an action is carried out). In the case of ずに,  this adjunctive に is attached to the 連用形 of the negative auxiliary verb ず (which winds up being just ず) to express how something is **not** carried out.

So in your example

> なにもわからずに死んでいく

ずに is being used to show how the action 死んでいく is not being carried out, i.e. 何も分からず(に).

A nice way this can be translated into English is "without ～ing", and carries the same meaning as 「～ないで」, but is more literary.

Comment: So then the ni in my context is being used as both ずに (verb negation) and as a connective form (like how the te form has a connective form to connect V1 with V2) in how the "ずに is being used to show how the action 死んでいく is not being carried out, i.e. 何も分からず(に)."

Comment: The に is not negating the verb. The に is being used to 'connect' in a sense the previous verb to the following verb, and the ず is being used to negative the previous verb.